# How I can update entity dialogflow since Nodejs?

Tags: dialogflow-es, access-token

There are someone who know how update a dialogflow entity with code.

I have been trying with the [API Rest of Dialogflow][1] but I dont know how get a Access Token by code.

I am trying update the entity with the Api Rest by Postman. I have generated the Access Token by Google Cloud SDK Shell but it show me this error:

"Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the dialogflow.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. "

...

Is this the best way? Am I in the correct way?
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes.entities/batchUpdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are in the correct way.

Please check the credentials once again, and make sure the path to Json is set.

If you are trying to do in postman, you have use bearer token for authorization.

generate bearer token by going to cmd and type :gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

Comment: Yes. I did it. That was the correct way. Method: projects.agent.entityTypes.entities.batchUp .. But it didn't satisfy my target because when a user tries to call this new entity Google Assistant doesnt understand even though Dialogflow do understand.

Comment: I wanted to add a new entity since a web and update in the Actions on Google that I had created.  As it didnt work I had to use system.entity "@any" and resolve with that. Thanks for all.